# Why is M.2 SSD so slow?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, samsung-ssd

I feel very upset and robbed, after having purchased 2x 1TB Samsung Evo 970 SSDs, with declared 2500+ read and write speed.

Reality is 3 to 8 MB/s:

[image]

Like really, what is this joke all about ? I've zipped the images and tried to extract them, **on the same drive**. They are way slower then my old pc from 2012 with big WD HDDs.

Am I the only one who experience such write/read degradation ?

Here are the results from CrystalDiskMark:

[image]

Updated post based on questions:

- CPU Load is not overheating, everything runs as usual, without any lags or slowdowns
- Antivirus is used as default windows 10 - Windows Security
- ZIP file is on the same disk "C:"

Comment: Can you run [CrystalDiskMark](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/crystaldiskmark/9nblggh4z6f2?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) against them and show the results?

Comment: all of these tests are showing 2500+ speeds, but I'm wondering about the real use cases.

Comment: Operations on many small files are always slower than on a single large file. Can you provide numbers from your HDDs for comparison?

Comment: I have a very large amount of small files... :( Should I change to some different configuration for better performance ?

Comment: Almost all drives only advertise their peak performance, i.e. their bulk sequential speeds. The top row. Basically transferring lots of small files will be down into the random and tiny read/writes which is the bottom most row. Sadly this will happen with pretty much any drive. Physical HDDs will try to mask it with their onboard RAM cache (64MB these days), while an SSD might not have that onboard memory.

Comment: My take on lots of tiny files: https://superuser.com/questions/1168014/nvme-ssd-why-is-4k-writing-faster-than-reading/1168029#1168029

Comment: this is crazy, now I can tell without a doubt that I'm robbed...like real, how should I know that there are 4 additional segments of tests behind the scene. If I ever saw a description showing values: 55MB/s to 3500MB/s, that would be enough transparent. Didn't expected that at all to be honest. Thank you for your kind information guys.

Comment: Do you have third-party anti-virus software or anything the like? What’s your CPU load? Is the ZIP file located on the same drive you are extracting to?

Comment: The problem is that there are many different workloads that have different demands and requirements and that is difficult to sum up with one nice catchy number for marketing purposes. High speed in one area can definitely translate to higher speed in others compared to a similar but slower drive so to an extent it is useful to know the peak speeds, but they don't show the whole story. As DanielB mentions antivirus programs scanning data as it is read and written can also bottleneck speeds. Windows Defender is relatively lightweight, but still has an effect.

Comment: Make sure the disc write cache has been accidentally disabled on the drives (check the SSD drives in device manager).

Comment: You are not being robbed.  That is just the way drives work.  If you were moving one large file, you would probably achieve speeds near 3000 MB/s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing a naive copy of a large number of tiny files and measuring the amount of *payload* transferred. To begin with, every byte transferred requires a read and a write. So that's a 50% cost right there.

But also, the control information for each file has to be read and control information has to be written for each file. In addition, the map of free space available has to be adjusted. That's another 50% cost right there.

But the major problem is simply that the operation is naive. That is, it is not optimized. The operation knows it has thousands of files to transfer and so it could pend dozens of reads for the various files. Similarly, when writing, it could create dozens of files and post writes to all of them. But it doesn't. It just copies the files one by one. That cuts performance by a factor of 10 or so for medium-sized files.

So you should expect about 1/40th of the advertised drive speeds.

For very tiny files, the measurement you are seeing is totally meaningless. After all, you can have zero byte files. And by this measure, no matter how fast you copy them, the speed in payload bytes per second is zero.

So this is not a useful way to benchmark drive performance and isn't even really measuring the speed of the drive but is instead measuring the ratio of useful data to metadata and the efficiency of the copy implementation.