# How can sysbench fileio throughput be only 6.92MiB/s on fast NVMe disk?

Tags: benchmarking

I followed [guide](https://github.com/sunknudsen/privacy-guides/tree/master/how-to-benchmark-server-performance-using-speedtest-and-sysbench#benchmark-disk) to benchmark WD_Black 1TB SN750 SE NVMe disk (read: 3600 MB/s, write: 2830 MB/s) on HP EliteDesk 800 G2 (i5-6500T).

```
$ sysbench fileio --file-total-size=8G prepare
…
8589934592 bytes written in 7.91 seconds (1035.26 MiB/sec).

$ sysbench fileio --file-total-size=8G --file-test-mode=rndrw run
…
Throughput:
    read, MiB/s:                  6.92
    written, MiB/s:               4.61

$ sysbench fileio cleanup

$ dd bs=512k count=2048 if=/dev/zero of=/root/data
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.817983 s, 1.3 GB/s

$ sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3

$ dd bs=512k count=2048 if=/root/data of=/dev/zero
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.497434 s, 2.2 GB/s
```

How can throughput be so slow given fast NVMe disk?

Comment: Random access is hard. https://superuser.com/questions/1168014/nvme-ssd-why-is-4k-writing-faster-than-reading/1168029#1168029

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Mokubai. The strange thing here is that I am getting 62.55MiB/s on 5$/month VPS… the above test is done on bare metal. Creating files on VPS ran at 99.50 MiB/s… it ran at 1035.26 MiB/s on bare metal. 10 times faster… how can throughput be 10 times slower? Makes no sense. 

Comment: Sadly a VPS is going to have very different performance. Unless you have a dedicated box you know has a direct attached NVMe then you might have some network SAN operating over some novel fabric with very different performance figures. I'd never try comparing a VPS to bare metal for any performance figures to be honest.

Comment: @Mokubai Agreed… but how can bare metal with NVMe be slower than VPS?

Comment: Strangely, I got better throughput using USB3 external disk on same computer (vs internal NVMe)… puzzled.